# OR Logic with Attribute Filters in Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a use case where I need to use OR logic with attribute filters. Here is the scenario, User has many roles and has an attribute called global. Below is the index block

```
define_index do
  has roles(:id), :as => :role_ids
  has global
end
```

And I need to get users with have roles with id 5 or the users  with global true. Here is the query I am trying to use

```
User.search(
     :sphinx_select => "*, IF(global OR role_ids = 5, 1, 0) AS program_global",
     :with => {'program_global' => true},
     :match_mode => :extended
)
```

This results in a syntax error -  unexpected TOK_ATTR_MVA near 'role_ids = 5, 1, 0)' . The problem here seems to be that role_ids is a MVA. I am using sphinx 0.9.9

Any help?

Comment: Try "(global | role_ids) =(5 | 1|0)" pipe symbol instead of 'OR'. I tried with old version not in new..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the answer given by Pat

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/thinking-sphinx/kxNIGP10hkQ

```
"*, IF(global OR IN(role_ids, 5), 1, 0) AS program_global"
```